# MongoDB- What is the efficient way to run same query on multiple collections, limit the results and sort them at the end

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume I have 3 collections and 3 collections have a `refId` and that `refId` values may or may not be available in all collections and all the collections have few common fields. So My question is I should be able to find the documents with any `refId` and return the `_id, refId, someCommonFields,dateCreated` fields from all the collections and at the end sort them by `dateCreated` and limit to `x` num. Assume each collection grows 100 documents for each `refId` everyday

Example collections:

**coll1**

```
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f3"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d804"), color:"red",someCommonField:"whocares", dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.870Z")},
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f4"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d804"), color:"green",someCommonField:"careswho",dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.879Z")},
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f5"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d805"), color:"red", someCommonField:"random", dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.876Z")}
```

**coll2**

```
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f6"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d804"), type:"book",someCommonField:"randomstring", dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.873Z")},
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f7"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d806"), type:"video",someCommonField:"ignoreme",dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.874Z")},
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f8"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d805"), type:"audio", someCommonField:"cool",dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.875Z")}
```

**coll3**

```
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09990f6"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d804"), name:"tom", someCommonField:"mongo4",dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.973Z")},
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09990f7"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d806"), name:"dom",someCommonField:"nodejs",dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.974Z")},
{_id:ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09990f8"), refId:ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d805"), name:"pom",someCommonField:"static", dateCreated:ISODate("2020-06-02T03:21:08.975Z")}
```

**Approach1: Using node js promise.all()**

lets assume I m using mongoose

```js
const promise1=db.coll1.find({refId:refId}).limit(10)
const promise2=db.coll2.find({refId:refId}).limit(10)
const promise3=db.coll3.find({refId:refId}).limit(10)
async function someRandomFn(){
       const [r1,r2,r3]=await Promise.all([promise1,promise2,promise3]);
       const results=[...r1,...r2,...r3];
       return results.sort((a,b)=>a.dateCreated-b.dateCreated).slice(10).map(({_id,refId,someCommonField,dateCreated})=>{_id,refId,someCommonField,dateCreated});
}
```

**Approach2: Using mongodb aggregate**
Do a `$match` followed by `$lookUp`, followed by `$project`. Once the same process is done on 3 collections sort and limit the pipeline.

Comment: One problem with using `$sort` after `$lookup` is it can't use an index to process the sort, so it would have to read all 3 collections in their entirety and then sort the result in memory.  If there is more than 32MB of data to be returned, it would have to use temporary files on disk for sorting, which is even worse performance.  It it an option to get the limit of documents from each collection and then interleave them in the client? That would allow better index use and reduce disk IO on the server.

Comment: I m planning to limit results for 20 at least. Most probably I will end up creating paging tokens and once a response is sent it will be in client state